# Regex Match Count

Tags: regex, vb.net, count, match

I'm trying to count the number of matches replaced in a string but the problem is that it will only count properly if the words to be replaced are spaced out or in each line. Example:

**ThewallThewallThewallThewallThewall**

In the string above I want to replace all the 'the' occurrences with the word cars. There are 5 occurrences of 'the' in the string. To replace I use this:

```
Private Function GetRegExpression() As Regex
   Dim result As Regex
   Dim regExString As [String]
   ' Get what the user entered
   regExString = txtbx_Find.Text    
   Dim baseRegex As Regex = New Regex("[\\.$^{\[(|)*+?]")
   regExString = baseRegex.Replace(regExString, "\$0")
   If chkMatchCase.Checked Then
     result = New Regex(regExString)
   Else
      result = New Regex(regExString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
   End If
   Return result
End Function

Private Sub btn_ReplaceAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ReplaceAll.Click

    Dim regCount As New Regex(txtbx_Find.Text)
    Dim matchCount As Integer = 0
    Dim replaceRegex As Regex = GetRegExpression()
    Dim replacedString As [String]
    ' get the current SelectionStart
    Dim selectedPos As Integer = TheTextBox.SelectionStart

    ' get the replaced string
    Dim aCount = regCount.Matches(TheTextBox.Text).Count

    replacedString = replaceRegex.Replace(TheTextBox.Text, txtbx_Replace.Text)
    ' Is the text changed?
    If TheTextBox.Text <> replacedString Then
        ' then replace it
        TheTextBox.Text = replacedString
        If aCount < 2 Then
            lbl_RepMade.Text = String.Format("{0} replacement successfully made.", aCount)
            Timer1.Start()
        ElseIf aCount > 2 Then
            lbl_RepMade.Text = String.Format("{0} replacements successfully made.", aCount)
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
    Else
        ' inform user if no replacements are made
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Cannot find ""{0}""   ", txtbx_Find.Text), Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code works fine and it counts the number of occurrences *if*:

the string is: ThewallThewallThewallThewallThewall and i Replace all the 'wall' occurrences (5) however if I want to replace 'the' with 'tree' then it reports as 0 matches replaced. I find this a very strange bug in my program. It's as if the first word in the string wont be replaced however the second word does.

What do I do to solve this?

**Update**

seems like this is a case-sensitive problem. I did some testing and if I want to find 'The' and replace it with whatever it shows the count. if I search for 'the' (lowercase) and replace with whatever then it will replace all but not show the count

**Update 2**

Before:

```
 Dim regCount As New Regex(txtbx_Find.Text)
```

After:

```
Dim regCount As New Regex(txtbx_Find.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Adding IgnoreCase solved my problem. It always searched for the exact way including the case the user had searched for and wanted to replace.

Comment: Are you sure the ignore case checkbox is checked?

Comment: If it's checked and the user finds for 'the' it wont do the replace because there was no match case to start with. If it is then it will only search and replace the matched case words. So my problem is that when it's not checked it will search for both uppercase and lowercase and IF there are lowercase then will count only the lowercase. Something is wrong with my uppercase findings..

Answer (score 0):

Here is how OP solves the problem:

Before:

```
Dim regCount As New Regex(txtbx_Find.Text)
```

After:

```
Dim regCount As New Regex(txtbx_Find.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

> Adding IgnoreCase solved my problem. It always searched for the exact way including the case the user had searched for and wanted to replace.